# Build Map With For Loop

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary

I am trying to add values to a map variable that takes int keys and char values. The map is to contain the positions of letters in the alphabet, and the corresponding letter at that position. For some reason, I am getting an error from the `.insert()` portion inside the for loop.

```
map<int, char> cipher;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    cipher.insert(i, char(97 + i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax when using a map:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    cipher[i] = char(97 + i);
}

//To use it
std::cout << cipher[letterindex] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it slightly different:

I will use `map::emplace` instead as it inserts a new element into the container which is constructed in-place with the given args(if it's not already there) and avoid unnecessary copy or move operations if possible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    cipher.emplace(i, char(97 + i));
}
```

try it -> https://ideone.com/pKf99l

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::make_pair`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    cipher.insert(std::make_pair(i, char(97 + i)));
}
```

More details here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair

The problem is there is no overload of the `insert` functions that takes separate key/value arguments.